# Setting Up HLF network V1.4 with tls enabled and kafka based ordering

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, tls1.2

I am creating an HLF v1.4 network with TLS enabled and Kafka based ordering, But when I am trying to create a channel it throws an error saying
[image: Error]

and when I saw the logs of orderer it is showing
[image: Orderer Logs]

Configs for TLS in network

Peer Configs

```
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/ca.crt
```

Orderer Configs

```
 # enabled TLS
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/server.key
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/server.crt
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/ca.crt]
```

Cli Configs

```
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/peer/peers/peer0.org1/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/peer/peers/peer0.org1/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/peer/peers/peer0.org1/tls/ca.crt
```

Can anyone help me in this regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the error says, bad certificate while creating a channel, orderer certificate is not found, that's why the error bad certificate.

In the compose.yaml file, set the environment variable

FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG, to see exactly what the error is.